# Maxwell equation and divergence theorem contradict?

Tags: electromagnetism, divergence-theorem

In my engineering mathematics class, I learned about Gauss' law and form of one Maxwell equation.
I learned that

$∇∙E=ρ/ε$

in Maxwell's equation

$∇∙E=0$

in process of proving Gauss' law.

force of electric field has inverse proportion so I understood ∇∙E=0.

but why $∇∙E$ is not zero in Maxwell's equation?

Comment: One is a free field, the other is in the presence of electric charge.

Comment: Second equation follows from the first equation where charge density $\rho$ is zero.

Comment: @CameronWilliams but isn't divE always zero??

Comment: No. div(B) is always zero (as far as we know, assumes that magnetic monopoles do not exist (i.e. analogues of electrons, protons, quarks, etc do not exist for magnetism)).

Comment: @CameronWilliams Electric force has form of solid angle multipled by charge divergence of solid angle is zero